# How to integrate GraphQl with Cypress

Tags: graphql, cypress

I have recently started working with Cypress and looking forward how to test GraphQL end points.

Answer (score 0):

Cypress is used to perform e2e tests, so it makes no sense to use Cypress if you need to test only endpoints. There are plenty ways of how to test GraphQL api, just try to google more and pick one.